# can a flash object be exported to a java application?

Tags: java, flash, animation, jframe

Is it possible to play a Flash object/file into a jframe < netbeans > / any java application ?
If so , how ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help. - https://jflash.dev.java.net/ 
Or - http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html